# cannot download pdf in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, download, readfile

I want to force browser to download a PDF file from server using `readfile` in php.
This is my code:

```
$file = '/DIR/file.pdf';
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
                readfile($file);
                exit;
            }
```

After that browser shows me some unknown characters instead of downloading the PDF file. I tried different browsers and none of them did work. **What should I do to force the browser to download the file?**

The output is this:

[image: Text]

Please note that the file downloads correctly if I type file dir in in the browser.

Comment: I think the content header is wrong, have you tried this: `header("Content-type:application/pdf");`?

Comment: Use `Content-Type: application/pdf`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I tried this but did not work

Comment: @MarkusZeller I tried this but did not work

Comment: `header('Content-Encoding: identity')` and also `header("Content-type:application/pdf")`

Comment: @DDS unfortunately did not work

Comment: You set HTTP headers. Have you verified they reach the browser?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález what does that mean? what should I do to ensure they reach the browser?

Comment: Hit F12 and find a tab labelled "Network".

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It does not reach the browser

Answer (score 0):

just set content type to application/pdf and the encoding to identity

```
 $file = '/DIR/file.pdf';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('HTTP/1.1 200 Ok');
            header('Content-Encoding: identity');
            header("Content-type: application/pdf");

            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
          //  header('Pragma: public'); //not needed (unless you're using HTTP 1.0)
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }else{
           header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not found'); //throws 404 not found if the server can't find / access the file
           echo ("file $file not found");
           exit;
```

}

On my local system it works (it opens adobe-pdf)

Last idea: check the file path, yours is absolute (searches from the file system root) you may have wanted to have it relative to the wwwroot of your webserver: `./DIR/file.pdf`

Comment: thanks for your reply but it's still not working. Should I change some setting in server?

Comment: anyway check that your server can handle application/pdf as a mime type

Comment: Perhaps it's because the page is cached. Empty your cache and try again.

Comment: @DDS how should I check pdf is a mime type?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I don't thnik so. I clear cache by CTRL+F5 and then re enter

Comment: it depends on your web-server

Comment: @DDS My path is from beginning of the serve root to the file. I think addresses are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. Then try to access to url this PHP-page directly.

```
<?php
    $file_url = "https://path/to/your/pdf";


    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
    readfile($file_url);

?>
```

Then paste this in your .htaccess

```
<ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
    SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.domain\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content- 
    Type, Accept, Authorization"
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help. The code works and browser force download the file. But there is another problem. The downloaded file is damaged and cannot be open by any PDF reader.

Comment: Please note that file on the server is OK. It opens and downloads correctly.

Comment: Could you try with another Pdf-file and see if the result is the same?

Comment: I uploaded a file from my PC to server and then use the URL of new PDF file. The result was the same. Downloaded PDF is damaged and could not be open.

Comment: Are you using http or https for your download link? Should be https

Comment: Also, try including your download link directly in your <a> tag. Like `<a href='forcedownload.php'><a/>`